# How to add check_box_tag for form builders?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a form for pets that have illness. I am getting an error saying: 
`undefined method check_box_tag for #`
This is how my tag looks for form builder. I prefer a check_box_tag instead of radio button. How do I use a check_box_tag for form builders?

```
      <p><%= form_for(@pets) do |f| %>
      <% @checkups.each do |checkup| %>
      <td><%= checkup.illness %></td>
      <td><%= @checkup.illnessname %></td>
      <%= f.check_box_tag :response, "a" %>
        <!-- many more illness options below -->

     <%end%>
     <%=f.submit%>
     <%end%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the form_builder 'f' if you'd like to use the '_tag' version. Just use check_box_tag without accessing it from the form builder.

So this will become:

```
 <%= check_box_tag :response, "a" %>
```

Or if the :response is an accessible field on @pets, you should do:

```
 <%= f.check_box :response, {}, "a" %>
```

*Notice the different API's (method signatures) for both methods.*

Also for reference, you should see: 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.htm